# Add colurs to statusbar in odoo10

Tags: colors, odoo, statusbar, odoo-10

Need to add colour in statusbar in odoo10 which available openerp versions
eg: `<field name = 'state' widget=statusbar clickabe= 'True' statubar_colors='{"new": "blue"}'>`

How add colours in statusbar in odoo10

Need different color for different states in status bar
For eg: Blue color for draft,green for progress, red for cancel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is two solution for your requirement:

1. If you need this behavior for only one Form view, Is simple as this:

just add `style` tag to beat the `css selector` generated by `Odoo`

```xml
        <style>
            .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled {
               background: yellow;
            }
            .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled::after {
               border-left-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        ...
        ...
        <field name ="state" widget="statusbar">
```

Here I used the same `css selector` because it's loaded after `Odoo selector` it is the one used, notice that my status bare button have `.disabled` class because it's `readonly` I think you have to change that `clickabe= 'True'` means it's not readonly.

2. if you want to have this for all your model here you need to use `css file` and add it to assets_backend template, make sure that your selector beat Odoo selector.

```xml
   <template id="assets_backend" name="backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/your_addon_name/static/src/css/your_css_file_name.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

Now I don't how you want to change the color exactly Here, you need to deal with `CSS` to select the **right element**,
for example if you want to make the status bar color `blue` only when the `"new"` value is `selected`, lucky for you
Odoo show the value `selected` in attribute `data-value` that doesn't change by translation.

```css
   .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled[data-value="new"] {
        background: blue;
    }
    .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled[data-value="new"]::after {
       border-left-color: blue;
    }
```

This is in Odoo 11, when I inspected the element, this what I noticed:

- status that is selected have class `btn-primary` the rest have `btn-default`
- readonly  have attribute `disabled="disabled"`  and class `disabled`

And just to show that this work Here is a screen shot of what I have, You may have some side effect, it's when you open some `record` in `popup` and this `form` is still shown in the web page, this will effect the record shown too if it have a `status` bare `widget`, because the `style tag` will be **removed** when the `form` view is **removed** from the web page.

[image: screen shot]

**Edits**:

Let say your selection has two values : new, valid

This will color new to blue if selected and valid to green fi selected

```xml
<style>

       .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled[data-value="new"] {
            background: blue;
        }
        .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled[data-value="new"]::after {
           border-left-color: blue;
        }

        .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled[data-value="progress"] {
            background: blue;
        }
        .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled[data-value="progress"]::after {
           border-left-color: blue;
        }

        .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled[data-value="cancel"] {
            background: red;
        }
        .o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status > .o_arrow_button.btn-primary.disabled[data-value="cancel"]::after {
           border-left-color: red;
        }
</style>
...
...
...
<field name="state" .....>
```

It's all about selecting the field by `data-value` Hope you get the idea. and this is easier than having to deal with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for response, Need Different color for different states

Comment: yes, you can do what ever you want I just told you, you have to use data-value to select different element and specify different color for each element.

Comment: Just edit your question and show different value of your field state, and what color you want for each selected value and I will help you with it, if you don't know how to do that, checkout my edits to have an idea on what  you should do

Comment: Very well explained @ElegantOdoo.

Comment: Hi, how can I implement this in a specific module only?

Comment: @user9523333 I explained at the end just define a style tag inside you form view, preferably before sheet tag and it will be applied only for that form view

Answer (score 0):

This feature was removed from Odoo a long time ago.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/5987

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/11199

If you need to add this feature you will have to create a new widget for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 inherit_id="web.assets_backend"
```

add style as you need, you can also give style in css