# Custom statusbar widget odoo

Tags: widget, odoo, statusbar, odoo-11

Hello I would like to customize the colour (CSS) of a status bar in Odoo
How can I custom the widget status bar **only for a specific view**?

```
<field name="state" data-name="custom_statusbar" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible=""/>
```

Comment: Add particular class to that specific view and then add css over that class.

Comment: I can't add a class on a view. Ex: <field name="my_bar" widget="statusbar" />. Odoo generate it's own html so ... I can't add a specific css class

Comment: Odoo should keep the class if you add it to the field. Try `<field name="my_bar" class="test" widget="statusbar" />`. Then you may need to set the css attributes to the children nodes with `!important` in your custom css file

Comment: You can check my answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726716/add-colurs-to-statusbar-in-odoo10/57786480#57786480